# Buttons do not align after bootstrap and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a main menu where you log in and sign up. It is created with bootstrap, css, and html. Things went pretty smoothly except for this last bit. The log in and sign up buttons keep sliding to the side whenever I make the webpage full screen. The mobile version does not do this. 
Here is a JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/aetw5a4h/

The button tags with the class btn-login and btn-signup are my concern they just do not align in the center.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-login col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 btn-login" value="Log In">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>    

<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">       
        <div class="signup-form">
            <label class="create-label">Create an Account</label>
            <label class="or"><span>or</span></label>
        </div> <!-- signup-form -->
    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="btn btn-primary-login col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 btn-signup" ui-sref="signup">Sign Up Free</button>
    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
```

here is their css:

```
.btn-login {
    background-color: firebrick;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
    width: 200px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:70px;
    display:block;
}

.btn-signup {
    background-color: firebrick;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
    width: 200px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:-200px;
    display:block;
}
```

[the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxm8w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really using the grid the way it's intended. If you apply it according to he [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) using:

```
container
  row
    col-*-*
```

you won't have any issues with your elements floating out of place.

**Working Example:**

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  background-color: #d00025;
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1200/900/?gravity=east');
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Candara', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo-login {
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: 170px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  z-index: 1;
}
.login-form {
  top: 90px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 25px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 100px 50px 50px 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}
.signup-form {
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 25px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
}
.input-label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.create-label {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
.or {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
}
.sub-section> span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.or > span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.form-control {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.btn.btn-login {
  background-color: firebrick;
  font-family: Candara;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid firebrick;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  display: block;
}
.btn.btn-signup {
  background-color: firebrick;
  font-family: Candara;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid firebrick;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -200px;
  display: block;
}
.social_media {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -75px;
}
.btn.btn-facebook {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-image: url(img/fb.gif);
  background-color: #3b5998;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.btn-gmail {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-image: url(img/g+.gif);
  background-color: #dc4a38;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.btn-primary-login {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #9e0b0f;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.btn.btn-primary-login:hover,
.btn.btn-primary-login:active,
.btn.btn-primary-login.hover {
  background-color: #84090D;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
/* styles for signup */

.uv-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 225px;
}
.sub-header {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 225px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.logo-signup {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 170px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px grey;
  z-index: 1;
}
.signup-header {
  top: 110px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 50px 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
}
.signup-form2 {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 25px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.btn.btn-facebook-signup {
  background-image: url(img/fb.gif);
  background-color: #3b5998;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  margin: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.btn-gmail-signup {
  background-image: url(img/g+.gif);
  background-color: #dc4a38;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  margin: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}
.social-btn-group {
  padding-left: 205px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.sub-section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
}
.field-label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.radio-inline {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.user-type {
  font-size: 75px;
}
.separator div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center" data-ng-controller="AuthenticationController">

      <form data-ng-submit="signin()" class="signin form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">

        <fieldset>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="logo-login">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/350/350/?gravity=north">
                </div>

                <div class="login-form">
                  <h1>United Volunteers</h1>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="input-label">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" data-ng-model="credentials.username" name="username" id="username">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="input-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="credentials.password" name="password" id="password">
                  </div>

                  <alert type="danger" data-ng-show="error" class="text-center text-danger">
                    <span data-ng-bind="error"></span>
                  </alert>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-login btn-login" value="Log In">Log in</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

      </form>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
            <div class="signup-form">
              <label class="create-label">Create an Account</label>
              <label class="or"><span>or</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary-login btn-signup" ui-sref="signup">Sign Up Free</button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="social_media">
              <a href="/oauth/facebook">
                <button class="btn btn-facebook"></button>
              </a>
              <a href="/oauth/google">
                <button class="btn btn-gmail"></button>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the clarfication :D ill try my best to make sure the grid system in my codes in future are in the proper order.

Answer (score 0):

In http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid you can find the following hierarchy:

1. Columns are the only children of rows
2. Rows must be placed in container or container-fluid

It means that you have to use those like this:

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also do not use col-* in button classes. You have to separete them like above example.

When I use those instruction in your project, "log in" button back to the center possition:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-login btn-login" value="Log In">Log in</button>
  </div>
</div>
```